# Kotlin - Set @Annotations . to function return types?

Tags: android, kotlin, annotations, kotlin-android-extensions

Is there a way to use annotations to declare a return condition for kotlin functions?

For example, I want to tell lint that my function will return an Android resource id at:

```
fun getImageId(): Int
```

I would want something as:

```
fun getImageId(): @DrawableRes Int
```

which fails

I thought it would make sense (I believe is possible in Java), because I may have something as:

```
 fun setImage(@DrawableRes res: Int) {
        myImageView.setImageResource(res)
    }
```

and call it as:

```
setImage(getImageId())
```

So that it has a chain of validations that the given `int` is actually a Res Id

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can do it with:

```
@DrawableRes
fun getImageId(): Int
```